# How to Declare and use a Generic TList of a Generic Record

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe2

I want to declare a generic record type such as

```
TMyGenericRecord<T, T1> = record
   X: <T>;
   Y: <T1>;
end;
```

Then I want to declare a TList of TMyGenericRecord but cannot seem to get the proper syntax for it.

```
TMyGenericList = TList<TMyGenericRecord<T, T1>>???
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: And you want to do this instead of using `TPair` why?

Comment: @warren perhaps the real code has three or four generic params

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Actually, it does have several, I'm still working on exactly how to build the structure.  Didn't see the need to complicate it in the example here.  WarrenP I was not aware of TPair, so thank you for the suggestion...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want to write it like this:

```
type
  TMyGenericRecord<T1, T2> = record
    X: T1;
    Y: T2;
  end;

  TMyGenericList<T1, T2> = class(TList<TMyGenericRecord<T1, T2>>);
```

You can then instantiate the type like this, for example:

```
var
  List: TMyGenericList<Integer, string>;
```

You can then declare a record that is compatible with this list like so:

```
var
  Rec: TMyGenericRecord<Integer, string>;
```

At which point

```
List.Add(Rec);
```

will compile. Although clearly you'd need to construct an instance of the list.

Comment: Thank you, just tried it, works beautifully.  If you don't mind explaining, why the declaration with "Class" in class(TList<TMyGenericList<T1,T2>>)?

Comment: The documentation (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declaring_Generics#Class.2C_Interface.2C_and_Record_Types) lists the types that can be declared with generic parameters. You might wish to write `TMyGenericList<T1, T2> = TList<TMyGenericRecord<T1, T2>>`, but according to the documentation (and the compiler), that is not possible.

Comment: I think another way to say it is that generic type aliases are not allowed.

Comment: @user Think about specifying a comparer if you need IndexOf and alike because the default comparer for records does a raw memory compare which might not be what you want.